# How to make div responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress to build my website and i have a section that contains a div of items displayed as a grid.Everything works fine except for the case when the grid is only with 1 item.I want this 1 item to be centered in the div and the whole div to be responsive
Here's my code:

```
echo '<section class="our-team" id="resources">';


                echo '<div class="container">';


                    echo '<div class="section-header">';


                        $zerif_events_title = get_theme_mod('zerif_events_title',__('Resources','zerif-lite'));//Title

                        if( !empty($zerif_events_title) ):
                            echo '<h2 class="dark-text">'.__($zerif_events_title,'zerif-lite').'</h2>';
                        endif;

                    echo '</div>';


                    if(is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-doctors' )):
                        echo '<div class="row" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 0.1s">';
                            dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-doctors' );
                        echo '</div> ';
                    else:

                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'resources', 'showposts' => '3', 'paged' => $paged) );
                    $count = $wp_query->post_count;

                    if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
                     $i =1;
                        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

                         $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_location', true);
                         $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID);

                         if($count == 1)
                         {
                         //
                         echo '<div  style="position:relative;left:33%">';
                         }
                         if($count == 2)
                         {

                         echo "<div class = 'col-md-6'>";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                         echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
                         }
                            if($url)
                            {
                            echo "<a href = ".$url.">";
                            echo the_post_thumbnail();
                            echo "</a>";
                            echo "<h6>";
                            echo the_title();
                            echo "</h6>";
                            echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,170);  



                            }
                            else{
                            echo "<a href = ".$permalink.">";
                            echo the_post_thumbnail();
                            echo "</a>";
                            echo "<h6>";
                            echo the_title();
                            echo "</h6>";
                            echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,170);  

                            }
                            echo "</div>";  
                             $i++;
                                if($i>3)
                                {
                                    echo "<br>";
                                    $i=1;
                                }

                        endwhile;
                        if($count > 2){
                        $page = get_permalink(  get_page_template_by_title( 'Resources' ) );
                            echo '<a style ="position:relative;top:50px" text-align="right" href = "http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=89"> View All -> </a>';
                            }
                    endif;


                    endif;




                echo '</div>';


            echo '</section>';
```

Comment: You need to post your static HTML so we can help.

Comment: This is PHP code, you can make your div responsive using bootstrap classes in the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

To make an element responsive, you need to take a look at the CSS and HTML, not your PHP.

For example, if your `DIV` has the class `responsive` (`<div class="responsive">foo</div>`), and you want it to be centered and have an adaptive width in relation to the window, your CSS could be:

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This would mean that the width is always exactly 100% of the window's width, and the text inside it will be centered.

[See W3Schools' Responsive guide for more information.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_responsive_intro.asp)